# Python PySerial mixed data in some sort of pattern

Tags: python, stm32, pyserial, usart

I am trying to **read** some data from STM32. I am using USART peripheral on MCU side in **transmit only** mode and FTDI FT232R (UART -> USB) cable which is connected to the PC. On my PC side I am using Python 3.11.1 with PySerial 3.5. Baud rate is 3MBaud (maximum of FT232R).

The problem is that the data seems to be "mixed" in some sort of pattern, if the frequency of sending the buffer is increased (not talking about UART frequency here). For example if I send my 32 bytes buffer every 1ms the data (utf-8 decoded) looks fine:

DATA looks as expected:

```
Line1: 1 // first line is expected to be random, because I randomly start Python
Line2: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 1
.... 
LineN: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 1
```

**but** if I send this buffer every 150us the data gets "mixed".

DATA looks mixed:

```
Line1:   9 10 11 12 13 1 // first line is expected to be random, because I randomly start Python
Line257: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 1 (here should be the numbers from Line1) 
Line258: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 1
Line381: 1 (here should be the numbers from Line257)
```

The Line257 is always problematic that is why I would say that the MCUs USART is not the problem and I also wouldn't expect this to be a hardware issue. Any idea what could be the problem, could USB/COM have some sort of overflow?

Python code:

```
import serial

# Specify the COM port (e.g., "COM4" on Windows or "/dev/ttyUSB0" on Linux)
com_port = "COM4"  
output_file_path = "serial_data.txt"  # Path to the output text file

# Open the serial port
ser = serial.Serial(com_port, baudrate=3000000, timeout=1)

try:
    with open(output_file_path, "w") as output_file:
        while True:
            # Read data from the serial port
            data = ser.readline().decode("utf-8")
            # Write data to file
            output_file.write(data)

except serial.SerialException as e:
    print(f"Serial port error: {e}")

finally:
    # Close the serial port
    ser.close()
```

Note that I am always running USART in transmit mode and I am reading data randomly.

Comment: What leads you to think 3000000 is a valid baud rate for the STM32?  And the FT232 only has a 128-byte receive buffer, and since it is a USB 2 full-speed device, it can only send a packet once per millisecond.

Comment: Theoretical STM32G474RET baud rate is 21.25MBaud, so I think there is no problem with STM32. Signal also looks nice on the scope.
Thanks for the info, I see that i have to look a little bit into USB 2.0 protocol...
I was a little bit deceived with the info from datasheet, where it is specified that the baud rate is up to 3M for this chip. Do I understand correctly, that the overall max transfer speed can't exceed 128*8/0.001 = 1.024 Mbit/s ?

Comment: The endpoint packet size in the descriptors is 64 bytes, less 2 bytes of overhead.  It's a bulk endpoint, so you CAN get multiple packets per frame.  One user did report getting just under 2Mbps with extremely careful tuning and timing, but I wouldn't count on that.  There's no buffering in USB.  I think you need to ratchet down your expectations.

Comment: @Flash375 This is a problem that the baud rate is not the same. When the baud rate of the reciving side is faster you will end up with data corruption and other intersting cases.  such as data-loss. I will start by matching the baud rate. Also I used pyserial with other MCUs and had no problems on windows.